# Create an array of items in a Select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class generated by XSD.EXE called `workOrders`.  The class has a member `Items` of type `workOrdersWorkOrder[]`.  I want to populate `workOrders` with LINQ.

I don't know how to populate my Items member properly.  This is where I need help:

```
        labels = result.AsEnumerable()//labels is of type workOrders
                    .Select(o => delegate()
                            {
                                new workOrders
                                {
                                    new Items
                                    {
                                        number = o.WorkOrder,
                                        Part = o.Part,
                                        Col3 = o.Col3,
                                        Qty = o.Quantity.ToString()
                                    }
                                };
                            }).ToList();
```

Note that this code doesn't work and is probably way off.  I wrote it that way to try and convey what I want to do.

In simpler cases (no member arrays) I have been able to do this via

```
.Select(o => new workOrder
                        {
                              number = o.WorkOrder,
                              Part = o.Part,
                              Col3 = o.Col3,
                              Qty = o.Quantity.ToString()
                        }).ToList();
```

But, in this case I don't know how to make the jump.

Thanks

Comment: @Tomas Jansson - I would like to populate workOrder.Items with workOrdersWorkOrder[] using Select()

Comment: Ok, I think my answer below might do that for you, but haven't tried it... and maybe a typo or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you need something more like this:

```
labels = 
    new workOrders
    {
        Items = result.Select(o => new workOrder
                    {
                          number = o.WorkOrder,
                          Part = o.Part,
                          Col3 = o.Col3,
                          Qty = o.Quantity.ToString()
                    }).ToArray()
    };
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track here.  I get a runtime error.  "Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."    If I take out the Qty it does seem to work.

Comment: Used SqlFunctions.StringConvert instead of ToString().  Now your solution works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right... the following might work:

```
labels = (from item in result.AsEnumerable()//labels is of type workOrders
         select new workOrders
                {
                    Items = new workOrdersWorkOrder[]
                    {
                        {
                            number = item.WorkOrder,
                            Part = item.Part,
                            Col3 = item.Col3,
                            Qty = item.Quantity.ToString()
                        }
                    }
                }
           }).ToList();
```

Haven't tried but it could work :). Also, it depends on what you data you have and what you expect as result. My code above will create a list of `workOrders` where each object will have one item in the list `Items`, but that might be correct.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I get "The name 'o' does not exist in the current context".  Seeing as there's no Select() I imagine that's why.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for that... to much copy paste. Change `o` to `item`. The linq variables is named `item` and not `o`, that is why you got the error.